# I want to implement onmouseUp event in select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

> I want to do some event after onmouseup but it is not working. I have
> pasted the code in js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5rvtLs38/7/

```
 let btn = document.querySelector('#selectTag');
 
   btn.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
     let msg = document.querySelector('#message');
     switch (e.button) {
       case 0:
         msg.textContent = 'Left mouse button clicked.';
         break;
       case 1:
         msg.textContent = 'Middle mouse button clicked.';
         break;
       case 2:
         msg.textContent = 'Right mouse button clicked.';
         break;
       default:
         msg.textContent = `Unknown mouse button code: ${event.button}`;
     }
   });
```

Comment: You should look into [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) which you actually need.

Comment: What should i need to choose for mouse event so that it can full fill up my task for onmouseup